# In CSS can I display:none (set aria-hidden="true") regarding aria label?

Tags: css

I'm using userstyles (stylish). I want to hide a promo on Google (`aria-label="promo"`). The promo asks me to make Google my homepage. `display:none` regarding the class in question also blocks the app-launcher so that's not an option. I see this:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="gb_ga gb_g">
```

In CSS I want to set "aira-hidden" to "true" regarding that class. Can I do that? Or is there another way to `display:none` for the part in question?

I'm extremely unfamiliar with aria-labels.

**Firefox inspect element of Google aria label "promo" aria-hidden="false"**
[image]

Comment: Maybe I have solved it or maybe it has disappeared of it's own accord for the time being, which it sometimes does. Do you think this will work: .gb_ga.gb_g[aria-label="promo"] {display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;}

Answer (score -1):

add this to your CSS to hide elements with aria-hidden="true"

```
[aria-hidden='true'] {
  display: none;
}
```